# How I can delete python 3.4 if i use just anaconda python

Tags: python, ubuntu, anaconda

I have a specific problem with python. I have on my ubuntu  two versions python3.4 and python3.6(from anaconda). I want use just anaconda python[current version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTZtJ.png)

But when i run script i have some problems with another python version
[another version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RtuuM.png)

How i can safe delete useless python 3.4.6?

Comment: Please take some time to review your question and fix the formatting issues.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo apt-get remove python3.4
```

anaconda should have set python3 as default python3.6 version

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not delete Python3 from your system, even if you have Anaconda installed, since there might be system software that:

1. was not tested with subsequent versions of Python;
2. might struggle finding Python from Anaconda.

What you should do instead is configure your IDE / environment to run Python script with Anaconda, e.g. by setting your `PATH` variable to point to your `anaconda/bin` directory or similar.
If you are using PyCharm, as it seems from the screenshot, you could set up your project to run the Anaconda Python without modifying your other command-line settings.